# check list string is null or empty

Tags: c#, linq, list, null

I have list  with empty space("*_*_")

```
List<string> MyList = (List<string>)Session["MyList "];

if(MyList !=null || MyList != "")
{
}
```

MyList != "" does not work if string has more space so

How can i check my list string is "" or null by using linq in c# ?

Comment: A list will never be `""`. What is it you want to check exactly?

Comment: Never say never . My List is "" sometimes :))

Comment: @JeroenVannevel List would never be empty string but `Session["MyList "]` might be just that, guess that's what the OP means.

Comment: Not duplicate , because this is list other one is only string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
if(MyList!=null || MyList.All(x=>string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
{

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if(MyList.All(s=>string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)))
{
      ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var emptyStrings = MyList.Where(p => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)).ToList();
var listWithoutEmptyStrings = MyList.Where(p => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)).ToList();
```

If you just want to check if the list contains one ore more such items:

```
if (MyList.Any(p => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)))
{
}
```

If you want to check if all elements are null or empty

```
if (MyList.All(p => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)))
{
}
```